# is there some kind of issue with the kml reader's ability to parse some addresses?

Tags: here-api

```
reader = new H.data.kml.Reader('https://heremaps.github.io/maps-api-for-javascript-examples/display-kml-on-map/data/us-states.kml');
```

// above works correctly

```
reader = new H.data.kml.Reader('https://www.wpc.ncep.noaa.gov/kml/winwx/Day1_psnow_gt_04inches.kml');
```

// row above gives kml parsing error. (address is correct)

```
reader = new H.data.kml.Reader('Day1_psnow_gt_04inches.kml');
```

// row above works correctly

Comment: Can you share the parsing error? I tried your code and all I get is CORS policy error.

Answer (score 0):

To translate KML objects to map objects, use the data module in the Maps API (mapsjs-data.js)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-data.js"></script>
```

**Note that you can load a KML file even from a different domain, if that domain supports [Cross-Origin Resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) Sharing.**